# C# проблема в скриптах Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Код - часть проекта игры на Unity, и проблема в том, что когда игрок пропускает 3 зомби или убивает 1 человека, игра должна останавливаться. До этого я успешно использовал такую реализацию, но тут что-то не так. В упор не вижу что.

```html
public class Ain_on_human : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public GameObject restart;
    public static bool lose_h=false;
    private void Awake()
    {
        lose_h = false;
    }
    void OnBoxCollider(Collider2D trig)
    {
        // Update is called once per frame
        if (trig.gameObject.tag == "Aim")
        {                
           lose_h = true; // когда становитса тру то во 2 скрипте состояния тру должно считыватса ифом но такого нет...

          // restart.SetActive(true);
        }          
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------
using UnityEngine;

public class player : MonoBehaviour 
{    
    public static bool kill = false;
    public static bool lose = false;
    private float num;               // counter zombies
    public GameObject restart;
    private void Awake()
    {
        lose = false;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "zombe_0")
        {
            num++;
            if (num >= 3)
            {
                 lose = true;
            }
        }
        //  Ain_on_human end;
      
        if (Ain_on_human.lose_h == true) 
        // problem  когда я обращаюсь к состоянию переменной 
        // и сравниваю ее с тру то стопаю всю игру 
        // (нужно так ибо 2 условия проиграша). 
        // Но оно не выполняет данную проверку , либо она всегда фолс... 
        // почему так  .. ибо до етого в программе уже юзал подобный подход
        {
            lose = true;
        }
        if (lose==true)
        {
            restart.SetActive(true);
        }
    }     
}
```

Прошу прощения за громоздкость, но оно не очень сложное, надеюсь.
Может, я протыкал в чем-то банальном.. 
Да и я в курсе, что, наверное, код подал не правильно. Просто не смог нормально инкапсулировать в сообщения, потому сделал так.

Comment: Возможно я криво описал проблему , потому повторюсь if (Ain_on_human.lose_h == true) не выполняемый а должн.. вот и вся проблема...

Comment: А у вас программа много-поточная или одно? Если многопоточная - добавьте `volatite`

Comment: попробую, но я в скриптах потоки вроде не использую, либо я чего-то не знаю (что очень вероятно)

Comment: volatile попробовал , посмотрел на docs.microsoft.com .. проблему не помогло , но спасибо за совет буду пробовать дальше

Comment: Не решение,просто совет.Если условие должно быть верно если bool == true, можно вместо `if (Ain_on_human.lose_h == true)` писать `if (Ain_on_human.lose_h)`

Comment: спасибо вам за замечания, на данный момент я знаю про такую возможность. Сейчас так и пишу ибо так короче .

Answer (score 1):

Я во всем разобрлса , if не может не работать ибо он прост как гильотина , все дело было немного в другом , в 1 скрипте обратите внимания на OnBoxCollider а должно быть OnTriggerEnter2D (используются для отслеживания состояния тригера (тега))
для того что б изменить состояния ststic bool lose во 2  скрипте нужно исправить 1 :

```html
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D trig)
    {
        
        if (trig.gameObject.tag == "human")
        {
            player.lose = truе;// set true in 2 scripts
        }
```